# In Sitecore, getting the rendering using context.Parameters["renderingId"] and GetItem

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

I have multiple renderings and I'm adding a help button to the Custom Experience Toolbar for each one that opens a new window and jumps to a specific anchor in the help file. I want the anchor to match the name of rendering such as "Container" or "Event List". So I made a custom command and I'm trying to get to the rendering item using this method but for some reason targetItem is always null. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Help : Command
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
        Assert.IsNotNull(context.Items, "context items are null");
        Assert.IsTrue(context.Items.Length > 0, "context items length is 0");

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        var renderId = context.Parameters["renderingId"];

        if (Sitecore.Data.ID.IsID(renderId))
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Items.Item targetItem =
                Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(renderId);

            if (targetItem != null) //never gets the item for me to access it's properties
            {
                data.Append("Rendering Name: " + targetItem.ToString() + "\r\n");
                data.Append("Rendering Display name: " + targetItem.Name + "\r\n");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. I needed Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase. Sitecore.Context.Database was pointing to core.

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer and mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0):

yes, whenever you do any operation on any sitecore admin site, you will always get a core database as a content database, so in order to get your thing working you have to first set your database as master, then you can use getItem method for retrieving the Item and its renderings.

Happy coding!!